# How do I store cookies while web scraping in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, request, python-requests

I am pretty new to the world of `web scraping` however I do know the basics, however this problem is stumping me. My goal is to scrape a website however the website requires `cookies`. Many users find the `cookies` they care about and their values after inspecting the page then set the cookies on the `get request` to access the website. However the website I am trying to scrape has numerous very complex cookies and I can’t quite understand them. Is it possible to have the cookies generated in the `get request` and store them in the session so that I don’t have to search a sea of cookies?

Any help would be appreciated

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url="website"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36'}

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
    r = s.post(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    print(soup)
```

I am currently using the above in order scrape product prices however I am being flagged as a bot.

Answer (score 2):

Use **[`requests.Session`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/)**:

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
response = session.get('https://google.com')
print(session.cookies)
```

The cookies get saved in `session.cookies` after each website you visit.

Comment: Maybe it’s because the site also requires JavaScript enabled, but I’ve tried something similar and the cookiejar is empty and I still can’t access the site.

Comment: @user14036256 This is why you should include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  I can't help you if I don't have code to test

Comment: My bad, I am new to posting to here and I have edited the question.